# Need help calculating MD5 Hashes In C#

Tags: c#

I am currently trying to make a program which calculates the MD5 hashes of files,
however, I am getting the following error:

System.ArgumentNullException: 'Path cannot be null.
Parameter name: path'

Here is my code so far

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Security.Cryptography;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace MD5Checker
    {
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnOpenFileDialog_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string fname = openFileDialog.FileName;
            string FILENAME = "@" + fname;
            txtFile.Text = FILENAME;
        }
    }
    public string FILENAME { get; set; }

    private void btnCalculateMD5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string results = CalculateMD5(FILENAME);
        richTextBox1.Text = results;
    }

    static string CalculateMD5(string filename)
    {
        using (var md5 = MD5.Create())
        {
            using (var stream = File.OpenRead(filename))
            {
                byte[] hash = md5.ComputeHash(stream);
                return BitConverter.ToString(hash).Replace("-", "").ToLowerInvariant();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please, add full stacktrace of your exception.

Comment: There is no need to add the @ before the fname. Use directly the value returned by OpenFileDialog

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are not updating the class' property but rather a local variable.

```
private void btnOpenFileDialog_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        string fname = openFileDialog.FileName;

        // this is FILENAME
        string FILENAME = "@" + fname;
        // here you use FILENAME instead of this.FILENAME
        txtFile.Text = FILENAME;
    }
}

// this is this.FILENAME
public string FILENAME { get; set; }

private void btnCalculateMD5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // uses this.FILENAME
    string results = CalculateMD5(FILENAME);
    richTextBox1.Text = results;
}
```

You can remove the variable so you always use the property. And while you are at it, you can start follow conventions and make it PascalCase so you remember it is a property and not a variable. Also, there is no need to add `@` before the file path:

```
private void btnOpenFileDialog_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        FileName = openFileDialog.FileName;
        txtFile.Text = FileName;
    }
}

// this is this.FileName
public string FileName { get; set; }

private void btnCalculateMD5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // uses this.FileName
    string results = CalculateMD5(FileName);
    richTextBox1.Text = results;
}
```

Comment: Oh, yes, but that @ before the fname seems totally unwarranted

Comment: yes but when i do that i still get an error:

System.NotSupportedException: 'The given path's format is not supported.'

Comment: @pika then you should show the code of your CalculateMD5

Comment: @pika Did you remove the `@`? A path cannot start with `@` in Windows

Comment: done that and everything works fine now, thank you for your assistance.